# Storing a elasticsearch index on an external drive

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

I want to use Docker to set up an elasticsearch instance. I want the documents to be index to come from an external drive and the index to be created on another external drive (there are Tb of documents).

This is my docker-compose.

```
version: '3'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

  python:
    build: .
    container_name: python
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - input_directory:_
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

volumes:
  esdata:
    driver_opts:
        type: "none"
        device: /media/user/usb_disk_name
        o: "bind"
```

I'm using ubuntu 22 and my disk capacity is 512Gb.
`docker compose up` throws `Error response from daemon: failed to mount local volume: mount /media/user/usb_disk_name:/var/lib/docker/volumes/elastic_docker_esdata/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory`. With sudo, the container is stopped with error 137 which, as I understand, is due to the container running out of memory.

Any ideas of how I can implement this solution on docker? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think your `docker-compose.yml` file missing the mount point for the `esdata` volume, try to update the yml file by following:

```
volumes:
  - type: bind
    source: /media/user/usb_disk_name
    target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

In the update `esdata` volume is defined with `local` driver. Then `docker-compose.yml` will look like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /media/user/usb_disk_name
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data

  python:
    build: .
    container_name: python
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - input_directory:_
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

volumes:
  esdata:
    driver: local
```